# Problem with jQuery clone(): clone input without value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery `.clone()` and it is working fine. However my problem is that when I clone my input field it also clones the value of the previous field. I don't want to clone the value. How can I overcome this issue?

Here is my code

```
function addrow(){
    var num     = $('.clonedInput').length;
    var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);     
    var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);
    $('#input' + num).after(newElem);

    jQuery('.clonedInput').each(function(){
        jQuery('#total', jQuery(this)).unbind('blur');
    });

    var ci = jQuery('.clonedInput:last');
    jQuery('#total', ci).blur(function() {
        addrow();
    });
}
```

Regards,

Faizan

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum).val('');
```

Comment: Yes I have tried it but its not working. Cloning the same value again

Answer (score 1):

I might be late with this, but it's not clear whether your "#input" is actually an input field. Only then you can set it's value.

After you place your cloned element, try:

```
newElem.find('input:first').val(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line after the clone

```
var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);
newElem.removeAttr('value');
```

or

```
var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum).removeAttr('value');
```

Comment: There is no need to do this via the attribute methods since there is a shorthand notation for it.

Comment: Really interesting: `removeAttr('value')` worked for me but setting `val("")` was not changing the value of the cloned `input`... was going crazy with this one! :)

Answer (score 0):

Works fine with me:

```
<div id="con">
<input id="input1" value="some text" />
</div>


$("#input1").clone().val("").attr("id", "input2").appendTo("#con");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sXL2b/

or by using insertAfter:

http://jsfiddle.net/sXL2b/1/

Try this instead of cloning:
http://jsfiddle.net/sXL2b/4/

Do you really need to clone?

Comment: if you check the source code of your example you'll see that although the value is not displayed the attribute is still populated with the cloned data.

Comment: @jbachman http://jsfiddle.net/sXL2b/2/ im showing input2, i can't see it right now just because i don't have firebug on this machine. It should technically clone it. Honestly i would probably do something different than clone though.

Comment: Yes that is my problem is. I am still getting the value cloned.

Comment: @Faizan i updated with a new one without clone. Can you go without cloning?

Comment: Yes I can use other solution to.. Basically I have a row of 5 input fields and I am adding a Add new row functionality on my Form.

Comment: @Faizan i think i know what might be the problem. maybe the name attribute? Heres another solution: http://jsfiddle.net/sXL2b/7/ although if you are just creating a blank field i would just go with a brand new one instead of cloning.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean all the inputs with .val(""):

```
<div class="">        
    <div id="references">
        <div class="">
            <div class="">
                <div class="">
                    <input type="text" name="name-reference" class="" placeholder="Name" >

                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <input type="text" name="relationship-reference" class="" placeholder="Relationship" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <div class="">
                <div class="">
                    <input type="text" name="employer-reference" class="" placeholder="Employer" >
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <input type="tel" name="phone-reference" class="" placeholder="Phone Number" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <button id="add" class="">Add</button>
            <button id="remove" style="display:none;">Remove</button>


    </div>
</div>
```

The script:

```
var reference_form_index = 0;
$("#add").on('click', function(){
   reference_form_index ++;        

    $(this).parent().parent().after($("#references").clone().attr("id","references" + reference_form_index));

    $("#references" + reference_form_index + " :input").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("name",$(this).attr("name") + reference_form_index);
        $(this).attr("id",$(this).attr("id") + reference_form_index);
        $(this).val('');
    });

$("#remove" + reference_form_index).css('display', 'inline');

$(document).on( 'click', "#remove" + reference_form_index, function(event){
        $(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove();
    } );

    $("#add" + reference_form_index).remove();
```

});

You can see it in action on:
http://jsfiddle.net/pnovales/yF2zE/5/